# python tab functionality to to look for file in directory when using raw_input()

Tags: python, tabs, user-input

user_input= raw_input("enter file path : ")

Raw_input() or input() in python3 takes just the filepath as string and passes them. Tab functionality is not there as in the terminal where you would get suggestions for files in the directory.

Is there any way user would be able to see the files in the directory by hitting tab?

I really need this functionality because the user is required to enter path for multiple files

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` can't do that. Consider using https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/cmd.html

Or use python readline directly.

Comment: Thank for your response! 
Could you give me an example how it could be accomplished with cmd? Where it would prompt the user for the location of the file but in a bash type environment. 
I would like the user to give the file path where each file is in different directory.

Comment: would it be possible to do this with os module?